# Bypass Tuya “smart” fan controller

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I just bought a fan that has a Tuya controller that uses a remote/wifi to control the fan and lights (see picture from instructions). The previous fan assembly was controlled by two switches, appropriately wired for the fan and light.

I plan on testing the controller outputs to the fan to see if it outputs the mains voltage and then cutting the fan connector and wiring it up like a traditional fan. My guess is the light is DC so I might just disconnect it. **Are there any dangers I’m not thinking about with my plan?** besides voiding warranties ;).

[image]

Comment: What make and model is the fan itself?

Comment: This is the amazon listing: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0CN36MBWR

"Sofucor 52" Smart Ceiling Fan, Indoor/Outdoor Ceiling Fans with Lights and Remote, Work with Alexa/Google/App, 3-Color Light 6-Speed Timing Reversible DC Motor for Bedroom Living Room Patio"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nope, you need a different fan

DC motor fans rely on a drive circuit inside the remote control to convert wall AC into DC, so you can't just wire the fan motor to wall power and expect it to do anything useful.  You'll have to return this heap of junk and buy a different fan (preferably *not* through Amazon, eBay, or any other Cheese-pipeline online vendor.)